# Python Disabling "X" Button with self.root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", event) doesnt work inside a class

Tags: python, tkinter

so first of all: im basically a noob in programming and i really dont know how to solve this "bug". Ive tried this in a simple testprogram and it worked but when i try to put this into my object-oriented-programmed class it simply doesnt work. If anyone out there knows a solution, please tell me what i am doing wrong and why it doesnt work. (The code itself works, i didnt copy the entire code here cuz it wouldnt participate for a solution (i guess)) Greetings !

```
class GUI(object):
 def __init__(self):
      self.root = Tk()
      self.root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", exit)
      """
      self.root.geometry(str(self.root.winfo_screenwidth())//2 +
                         "x" +
                         str(self.root.winfo_screenheight())//2)
      """

      self.xSize = 415
      self.ySize = 570
      self.root.geometry(str(self.xSize) +
                         "x" +
                         str(self.ySize)) # Fenstergröße

      self.root.title("P+R Anwesenheit") # Fenstername

      self.root.iconbitmap("icon.ico") # Fenstericon

      self.root.resizable(False, False) # Sperren der Fenstergröße

      #self.root.overrideredirect(True)


      self.pixelVirtual = PhotoImage(width=1, height=1) #Dazu da um Widgetgrößen in Pixel angeben zu können


      self.kalenderWoche = datetime.date(time.localtime()[0], time.localtime()[1], time.localtime()[2]).isocalendar()[1] # Kalenderwoche des aktuellen Tages
      self.groupMode = 2 # 1: Füllen bis zum unteren Rand/ 2: Gleichmäßige Aufteilung (auf 2 Reihen)
      self.namenNachnamenListe = listeAuslesen() #Liste der NACHNAMEN aller Mitarbeiter aus mitarbeiter.txt
      self.mitarbeiterListe = self.namenNachnamenListe[0] #Einlesen der Mitarbeiter aus mitarbeiter.txt
      self.aktiveLabelListe = [] #Liste der Anwesenheitsanzeigenden Label
      self.aktiveNamenLabelListe = [] #Liste der Namenslabel der Mitarbeiter
      self.labelErstellen = self.labelErstellen() #Aufruf der Methode um alle Labels der GUI zu erstellen
      self.buttonsErstellen = self.buttonsErstellen() #Aufruf der Methode um Button zu erstellen
      self.namenListe = [] #Fix-Textdateien-Liste
      self.buttonState = False #Vergrößern/-kleinern Button Status
      self.loginLogs = loginLogsTxt
      self.monatsListe = ["Januar", "Februar", "März",
                          "April", "Mai", "Juni",
                          "Juli", "August", "September",
                          "Oktober", "November", "Dezember"]

      #Fix für den Fall von Mitarbeitern mit gleichem Nachnamen (oder teilweise gleichem Nachnamen)
 
      for i in self.namenNachnamenListe[1]:
           self.namenListe.append(open(pathAnwesenheitsauslese+"\\"+i+"Logoff.txt", "w+"))
      for i in self.namenListe:
           i.close()
           
           
      self.fixDeleted = False #Fix angewendet/oder nicht

      #Binding

      self.root.bind('<Double-Button 1>', self.changeSize2)

 def exit(self):
      pass


 def destroyWindow(self):
      copy2("loginLogs.txt", "logs" + "/" + "loginLogs"+str(time.localtime()[2])+";"+str(time.localtime()[1])+";"+str(time.localtime()[0])+".txt")
      loginLogsTxt.close()
      os.remove("loginLogs.txt")
      self.root.destroy()
      .
      .
      .
```

Comment: What does "simply doesnt work" mean?  Error message?  Incorrect behavior?  The one thing I see wrong is that you're binding the window close event to `exit` (the built-in function) rather than `self.exit` (the method of your class).

Comment: Replace ```exit``` with ```self.exit``` (in line 4). Also, in the ```exit``` function, use something like ```return None``` if ```pass``` doesn't work.

Comment: If you just want to *disable the "x" button*, just change to `self.root.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', 0)`.